# How do we define multiple null values while using nzload with netezza?

Tags: sql, database, odbc, netezza

I am trying insert data into the netezza box. I have a pipe-delimited file wherein I want multiple variations of 'none'(i.e. 'None', 'NONE','none') be treated as NULL. While '-nullvalue' option does work for one variation at a time it doesn't allow me to set multiple variations to be treated as NULL.

Moreover multiple dfinition of the nullvalue option in the cf too doesn't help

Comment: use `LOWER(fieldname)` for the filter.

Comment: @vkp But I am not filtering it field wise, nzload does it for all the fields at one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 7.2, *nzload* does not allow multiple values for the -nullvalue option.  However, the 4 character value that you ***can*** specify is case insensitive, which allows for your particular sample case of -nullvalue of 'None' to match with 'NONE', 'none', 'NoNe', etc.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table null_test (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
CREATE TABLE

$ cat test.txt
1|NONE|1
2|None|2
3|NoNe|3


$ nzload -db testdb -df test.txt -t null_test -delim \| -nullvalue 'None'
Load session of table 'NULL_TEST' completed successfully

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from null_test where col2 is null;
 COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------+------+------
    1 |      |    1
    2 |      |    2
    3 |      |    3
(3 rows)
```